# estimate to show bilinear form continouus

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, finite-element-method

Consider the bilinear form 
$$a(u,v)=2\mu\int_\Omega \mathrm{trace}\left(\varepsilon(u)^T\varepsilon(v)\right)dx + \lambda\int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(u)\mathrm{div}(v)dx$$
with $\varepsilon(u)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\nabla u+\nabla u^T\right)$ and $u:\Omega\subset\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$.

My textbook says that we have $|a(u,v)|\leq d(\lambda+\mu)\|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}$ for all $u,v\in (H^1(\Omega))^3$, but I don't quite know how to get there.

I think by Cauchy-Schwarz we have 
$$\left(\int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(u)\mathrm{div}(v)dx\right)^2\leq\int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(u)^2dx\cdot\int_\Omega \mathrm{div}(v)^2dx\leq \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2dx\cdot \int_\Omega |\nabla v|^2dx$$
and hence an estimate $\int_\Omega\mathrm{div}(u)\mathrm{div}(v)dx\leq \|u\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2$.

But how can I estimate the first integral? Can anyone give me an input on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as well use Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\int_\Omega trace(\epsilon(u)^T\epsilon(v)) \le
c \|\epsilon(u)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}  \|\epsilon(v)\|_{L^2(\Omega)} 
\le c \| \nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}  \|\nabla v\|_{L^2(\Omega)} 
$$

Comment: oh, that's most certainly easier than I thought it was. Thanks!